# how to get one activity with background and another one activity tranparent backround color in android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am new to toolbar I am creating activity in android studio 1.4 ,how to create different different tool bar line in my first activity i need firsts activity should be tansparent color how to create that any one please help ,here below my style

Style.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a color on any view like #00xxyyzz:

```
#00000000
#00ffffff
```

Or set background:

```
background="@null"
```